# Send object to client via Socket.io (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, object, server, socket.io, client

I have the following code written on the node.js side:

```
var filtered = quadtree.filter(function (element) {
        return element.x > min
    })

    console.log(typeof filtered);//object

    socket.emit("Sonuç", filtered);
```

Here's the html code:

```
 socket.on("Sonuç", function (data) {

            console.log(data)
        });
```

There is no connection problem between server and client. I have a variable named filtered on the server side, and I learned that this variable is the object of its type. I do not have anything to send it to the client side and print it on the screen. What function should I use in the code section?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know when you send from server to client in time?
If you send it in `connection` then you need to open the client first, then start the server then the server sends the data and the client can receive the data.

```
// server
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    var filtered = {key: 'value'};

    socket.emit("Sonuç", filtered);
```